# Oracle 11.2.0.3 - Move Java objects from schema to schema

Tags: java, oracle, loadjava

I'm using Oracle 11.2.0.3 and have existing Java classes loaded to a schema called ABC.
I have a requirement to move those classes to a different schema DEF on the same DB instance.

The easy way would've been to simply `loadjava` all the classes to the new schema.
Unfortunately I don't have the sources or the compiled classes.

How would I go accomplishing this?
I thought of 2 possibilities, is either of them really possible?

1. Maybe some command exist that moves such Java objects, like `movejava` ?
2. Unload the classes so they exist on the file system, and then `loadjava` to the new schema

I think the site and the people here are amazing!
Please try to help me.

Answer (score 1):

You could export the class objects from one schema and import them into the other.  Use `expdp` and `impdp` with the option `include="JAVA_CLASS"`.  If you are not familiar with these utilities, consult the Oracle Utilities manual for more info.

See https://community.oracle.com/thread/2232825?tstart=0 for some examples.